# How to disable contextualMenu (customized) in webview?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

I implemented the  `contextMenuItemsForElement'  for`WebView`

```
 - (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
{

    NSMenuItem* newMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"NewMenuItem" action:@selector(newContextualMenu:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    [newMenuItem setEnabled:YES];
    NSArray *menuItemArray =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:newMenuItem];
    return menuItemArray;
}
```

I tried `[newMenuItem setEnabled:NO];` to disable the contextual menu in the `WebView`, but it did not work. Am I missing any thing?

Comment: Just wondering, is my solution ok?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the contextual menu in `WebViews` automatically determines the state of its `NSMenuItems`, which is probably why manual state setting doesn't work (`-setEnabled:`).

Because `- (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems` is called every time there's a right click the easiest thing to do would be to not add the `NSMenuItem` when you don't need it, but that's probably not what you want.

I don't know of a way to enable [manual menu enabling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000261-74276) for a `WebView`.  Your best bet would probably be to take advantage of the validation mechanisms already in place in unison with [automatic menu enabling](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000261-74653).

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)item {
    BOOL shouldEnable = ... 
    if ([item action] == @selector(newContextualMenu:) &&
        !shouldEnable) {
        return NO;
    }
    return [super validateMenuItem:item]; // only use if super implements
}
```

This would be defined where your action is defined, because it searches for both of them in the same place.

- Relevant [Menu Enabling/Disabling Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html).
- Relevant [Menu
  Enabling Validation Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).